# How is dependency inversion related to higher-order functions?

Tags: functional-programming, solid

Today I've just seen this article which described the relevance of SOLID principle in F# development-

[F# and Design principles – SOLID](http://web.archive.org/web/20120205110054/http://moiraesoftware.com/blog/2011/08/22/fsharp_solid/)

And while addressing the last one - "Dependency inversion principle", the author said:

> From a functional point of view, these containers and injection concepts can be solved with a simple higher order function, or hole-in-the-middle type pattern which are built right into the language.

But he didn't explain it further. So, my question is, how is the dependency inversion related to higher order functions?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Dependency Inversion in OOP means that you code against an interface which is then provided by an implementation in an object.

Languages that support higher language functions can often solve simple dependency inversion problems by passing behaviour as a function instead of an object which implements an interface in the OO-sense.

In such languages, the function's signature can become the interface and a function is passed in instead of a traditional object to provide the desired behaviour. The hole in the middle pattern is a good example for this.

It let's you achieve the same result with less code and more expressiveness, as you don't need to implement a whole class that conforms to an (OOP) interface to provide the desired behaviour for the caller. Instead, you can just pass a simple function definition. In short: Code is often easier to maintain, more expressive and more flexible when one uses higher order functions.

**An example in C#**

Traditional approach:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> FilterCustomers(IFilter<Customer> filter, IEnumerable<Customers> customers)
{
    foreach(var customer in customers)
    {
        if(filter.Matches(customer))
        {
            yield return customer;
        }
    }
}

//now you've got to implement all these filters
class CustomerNameFilter : IFilter<Customer> /*...*/
class CustomerBirthdayFilter : IFilter<Customer> /*...*/

//the invocation looks like this
var filteredDataByName = FilterCustomers(new CustomerNameFilter("SomeName"), customers);
var filteredDataBybirthDay = FilterCustomers(new CustomerBirthdayFilter(SomeDate), customers);
```

With higher order functions:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> FilterCustomers(Func<Customer, bool> filter, IEnumerable<Customers> customers)
{
    foreach(var customer in customers)
    {
        if(filter(customer))
        {
            yield return customer;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the implementation and invocation become less cumbersome. We don't need to supply an IFilter implementation anymore. We don't need to implement classes for the filters anymore.

```
var filteredDataByName = FilterCustomers(x => x.Name.Equals("CustomerName"), customers);
var filteredDataByBirthday = FilterCustomers(x => x.Birthday == SomeDateTime, customers);
```

Of course, this can already be done by LinQ in C#. I just used this example to illustrate that it's easier and more flexible to use higher order functions instead of objects which implement an interface.

Comment: A bit of example please? Or maybe link(s) for example.

Comment: Hold on, I'm gonna write you a good example.

Comment: Nice example. However, like Gulshan I'm trying to find out more about functional programming and I was wondering if this kind of "functional DI" doesn't sacrifice some rigor and significance compared to "object oriented DI". The higher order signature only states that the function passed must take a Customer as a parameter and return a bool whereas the OO version enforces the fact that the object passed *is* a filter (implements IFilter<Customer>). It also makes the notion of filter explicit, which could be a good thing if it is a core concept of the Domain (see DDD). What do you think ?

Comment: @ian31: This is an interesting topic indeed! Anything that is passed to FilterCustomer will behave as some sort of filter implicitly. When the filter concept is an essential part of the domain and you need complex filter rules that are used multiple times accross the system, it's sure better to encapsulate them. If not or only to a very low degree, then I'd aim for technical simplicity and pragmatism.

Comment: @ian31: I completely disagree. Implementing `IFilter<Customer>` is no enforcement at all. The higher-order function is vastly more flexible, which is a big benefit, and being able to write them inline is another huge benefit. Lambdas are also much easier able to capture local variables.

Comment: @DeadMG: You're looking at it from a technical perspective. From that point of view, I concur. But ian31 is looking at it from a DDD perspective. The concrete filters add value to an ubiqitous language when they're a core concept of the domain model. Also they can help enforcing the DRY principle.

Comment: @DeadMG : if compile-time checking that the object the developer passes to the method implements IFilter<Customer> isn't enforcement, I don't know what it is... As a matter of fact, it's even a *contract* the developer can't claim he isn't aware of, because it's explicitly stated that the thing must be a Filter. I perfectly realize the power of having a higher-order function in the discussed example, all I'm saying is I wonder if the tradeoff for that power isn't a lack of readability / clear domain concepts expressed in code. But maybe I'm wrong and functional languages allow that too ?

Comment: @DeadMG: This question has 6 upvotes, yet, my answer doesn't seem to statisfy most of the readers. Can you suggest improvements? I know that you're a competent guy from your answers. Should I include the difference between higher order functions and mere function pointers maybe?

Comment: @ian31: The function can also be verified at compile-time. You could also write a function, name it, and then pass it as an argument as long as it fullfills the obvious contract (takes customer, returns bool). You needn't necessarily pass a lambda expression. So you can cover that lack of expressiveness to a certain degree. However, the contract and its intent is not as clearly expressed. That's a major disadvantage sometimes. All in all it's a matter of expressiveness, language and encapsulation. I think you have to judge each case by itself.

Comment: This example reminds me of this answer- http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75442/how-would-you-teach-c-delegate-to-a-newbie/75452#75452
Folks can have a look to have an easy to understand idea of .net delegates.

Comment: For those interested in the comments of this answer see also [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/286942/is-the-semantic-contract-of-an-interface-oop-more-informative-than-a-function)

Comment: Many functional languages also allow you to create a type that encapsulates a function as well

Comment: if you feel strongly about clarifying the semantic meaning of an injected function, you can in C# name function signatures using delegates: `public delegate bool CustomerFilter(Customer customer)`. in pure functional languages like haskell, aliasing types is trivial: `type customerFilter = Customer -> Bool`

Comment: One issue with this example is that it's starting from a non-OOP, very functional starting point. In OOP you don't generally have a class to just filter arbitrary things (thats what LINQ is for). If you're passing high level functions in an OOP language like C# then chances are its not an object, its a function! You also miss out on the benefits of interfaces, such as: adding a new function doesn't require adding extra parameters across your code base. Interfaces group functionality for _high cohesion_, which you miss if you use function passing.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to change the behaviour of a function

```
doThis(Foo)
```

you could pass another function

```
doThisWith(Foo, anotherFunction)
```

which implements the behaviour you want to be different.

"doThisWith" is a higher-order function because it takes another function as an argument.

For example you could have

```
storeValues(Foo, writeToDatabase)
storeValues(Foo, imitateDatabase)
```

Answer (score 6):

Short Answer:

Classical Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control uses a class interfaces as placeholder for dependant functionality. This interface is implemented by a class.

Instead of Interface/ClassImplementation many dependencies can be easier implemented with a delegate function.

You find an example for both in c# at [ioc-factory-pros-and-contras-for-interface-versus-delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404084/ioc-factory-pros-and-contras-for-interface-versus-delegates).

Answer (score 2):

Piggy-backing off of LennyProgrammers example...

One of the things that the other examples missed is that you can use higher order functions together with partial function application (PFA) to bind (or "inject") dependencies into a function (via its argument list) to create a new function.

If instead of:

```
doThisWith(Foo, anotherFunction)
```

we (to be conventional in how P.F.A. usually is done) have the low level worker function as (swapping arg order):

```
doThisWith( anotherFunction, Foo )
```

We can then *partially apply* doThisWith like so:

```
doThis = doThisWith( anotherFunction )  // note that "Foo" is still missing, argument list is partial
```

Which allows us later to use the new function like so:

```
doThis(Foo)
```

Or even:

```
doThat = doThisWith( yetAnotherDependencyFunction )
...
doThat( Bar )
```

See also:  https://ramdajs.com/docs/#partial

... and, yeah, adders/multipliers are unimaginative examples.  A better example would be a function that takes messages, and logs them or emails them depending on what the "consumer" function passed in as a dependency was.

Extending this idea, still longer argument lists can be progressively narrowed down to increasingly specialized functions with shorter and shorter argument lists, and of course any of these such functions can be passed to other functions as dependencies to be partially applied.

OOP is nice if you need a bundle of things with multiple closely related operations, but it turns into make-work to make a bunch of classes each with a single public "do it" method, a la "The Kingdom of Nouns".

Comment: Your explanation made me understand the naming “dependency injection” better, when you talk about `consumer`

Answer (score 1):

Compare this:

```
String[] names = {"Fred", "Susan"};
List<String> namesBeginningWithS = new LinkedList<String>();
for (String name : names) {
    if (name.startsWith("S")) {
        namesBeginningWithS.add(name);
    }
}
```

with:

```
String[] names = {"Fred", "Susan"};
List<String> namesBeginningWithS = names.stream().filter(n <- n.startsWith("S")).collect();
```

The second version is Java 8's way of reducing boilerplate code (looping etc) by providing higher-order functions like `filter` which allows you to pass the bare minimum (i.e. the dependency to be injected - the lambda expression).